# Extracting rows for which a column's value changes from one date to the next in R

Tags: r, date

Good evening! I have the following data.frame from which I would like to extract rows for which the qualifier changes from one month to the next. I have no idea how to approach this, unfortunately...

Data:

```
id <- c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D")
qualifier <- c("G","H","I","I","I","H","Y","I","I","I","I","I")
date <- c("01/31/15","01/31/15",'01/31/15','01/31/15','02/28/15', "02/28/15", "02/28/15","02/28/15","03/31/15","03/31/15","03/31/15","03/31/15")
sample.data <- data.frame(id,qualifier,date)
```

The "id" is unique for any given date but may or may not exist on other dates. Each "id" has a qualifier "I" or "H". All dates are month-end. I would like to extract all rows for which the id's qualifier changes from either "I" or "G" to "H" or "Y" from one month to the next. So, to specify, only changes from 01/31/15 to 02/28/15 would be relevant, not changes from 01/31/15 to 03/31/15. Given the data.frame above, the change I would be interested in would be row 7, when the qualifer for "id" C changes from "I" (from row 3) to "Y" . Ideally, the extracted row 7 would have the value of the qualifier from row 3 as well.

The result should look something like this:

```
id   qualifier  date       qualifier.previous.month
C    H          02/28/15   I
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Change the date to a Date format
sample.data$date <- as.Date(sample.data$date, format = "%m/%d/%y")

# Collect the month value from the date
sample.data$month <- as.numeric(format(sample.data$date, "%m")) 

# Create a copy of the sample dataframe
sample.data_shifted <- sample.data

# Shift the months by one in the copied dataframe
sample.data_shifted$month <- sample.data_shifted$month + 1

# Merge the dataframes, so each ID/month row has the current and previous month qualifier 
sample.data_merged <- merge(
  sample.data_shifted, sample.data, 
  by = c("id", "month"), 
  suffixes = c(".previous.month", ".current.month")
  )

# Tidying up dates
sample.data_merged$date <- sample.data_merged$date.current.month

sample.data_merged <- subset(sample.data_merged, select = -c(date.previous.month, date.current.month))

# We create a logical vector telling us which qualifiers changed between which months
previous_month_ig <- sample.data_merged$qualifier.previous.month %in% c("I", "G")
current_month_hy <- sample.data_merged$qualifier.current.month %in% c("H", "Y")

# Now we only look at IDs/months where the qualifier changed from I/G to H/Y
sample.data_final <- sample.data_merged[previous_month_ig & current_month_hy, ]

sample.data_final

  id month qualifier.previous.month qualifier.current.month       date
5  C     2                        I                       Y 2015-02-28
```

This should fit your specifications - it's a bit lengthy to make it clearer. The idea here is to merge back onto your dataframe with the months shifted by one. This should work if you only have one date per month.

Comment: Perfect solution, @ashetty! Thank you very much for that! 100% spot-on!

Comment: I was lucky that I didn't post the question three days ago, given that you just joined two days ago...'8) Thanks again!

Comment: ha no worries, happy to help :)

Comment: Hi ashetty, sorry for opening up this again, but I'd have a follow-up question whose answer might be obvious to you but, unfortunately not to me. I tried several work-arounds - to no avail. Your solution works perfectly fine as long as there are only dates within one year. Since my data spans several decades, the months-based solution unfortunately doesn't work. Would you happen to have a solution to that, by chance? Sorry for asking so bluntly! If you don't have one, I will keep trying 8). Thanks in advance for your consideration! Have a good night!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a base R option using `ave` within `transform` could help

```
transform(
  sample.data,
  qualifier.previous.month = ave(qualifier, id, FUN = function(x) c(NA, x[-length(x)]))
)
```

which gives

```
   id qualifier     date qualifier.previous.month
1   A         G 01/31/15                     <NA>
2   B         H 01/31/15                     <NA>
3   C         I 01/31/15                     <NA>
4   D         I 01/31/15                     <NA>
5   A         I 02/28/15                        G
6   B         H 02/28/15                        H
7   C         Y 02/28/15                        I
8   D         I 02/28/15                        I
9   A         I 03/31/15                        I
10  B         I 03/31/15                        H
11  C         I 03/31/15                        Y
12  D         I 03/31/15                        I
```

---

A `data.table` option using `shift` can make it as well

```
> setDT(sample.data)[, qualifier.previous.month := shift(qualifier), id][]
    id qualifier     date qualifier.previous.month
 1:  A         G 01/31/15                     <NA>
 2:  B         H 01/31/15                     <NA>
 3:  C         I 01/31/15                     <NA>
 4:  D         I 01/31/15                     <NA>
 5:  A         I 02/28/15                        G
 6:  B         H 02/28/15                        H
 7:  C         Y 02/28/15                        I
 8:  D         I 02/28/15                        I
 9:  A         I 03/31/15                        I
10:  B         I 03/31/15                        H
11:  C         I 03/31/15                        Y
12:  D         I 03/31/15                        I
```

Comment: Thank you too, @ThomasIsCoding!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

id <- c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D")
qualifier <- c("G","H","I","I","I","H","Y","I","I","I","I","I")
date <- c("01/31/15","01/31/15",'01/31/15','01/31/15','02/28/15', "02/28/15", "02/28/15","02/28/15","03/31/15","03/31/15","03/31/15","03/31/15")
sample.data <- data.frame(id,qualifier,date)

setDT(sample.data)

sample.data[, qualifier.previous.month := shift(.SD, 1, 0, "lag"), by = id]
> sample.data
    id qualifier     date qualifier.previous.month
 1:  A         G 01/31/15                        0
 2:  B         H 01/31/15                        0
 3:  C         I 01/31/15                        0
 4:  D         I 01/31/15                        0
 5:  A         I 02/28/15                        G
 6:  B         H 02/28/15                        H
 7:  C         Y 02/28/15                        I
 8:  D         I 02/28/15                        I
 9:  A         I 03/31/15                        I
10:  B         I 03/31/15                        H
11:  C         I 03/31/15                        Y
12:  D         I 03/31/15                        I
```

Comment: Thanks to you as well, @tester!